# $_get and session. Can't get it to work

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
<?php
$lang = $_get["lang"];
if (($lang == "fr"))
{
    session_destroy();
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['lang'] == "fr";  
}

if (($lang == "en"))
{
    session_destroy();
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['lang'] == "en";      
}

if (isset($_SESSION['lang']))
{
    $lang = $_SESSION['lang'];
}
else
{
    $lang = "fr";            
}
?>
```

I just can't seem to get it to work and I tried a lot of different things. Just need a direction to the mistake.

It's running on PHP5 on an Apache server if that's any help.

Even without the session I can't even get the $_get to work. With normally is never the case.

Comment: Maybe you want to be using `$_GET` rather than `$_get`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have re-factored your code to make it easier to work with in the future. As Pekka says and I asked perhaps you need/want $_GET.

```
<?php
session_start();

$language = $_GET['lang'];

$allowable_languages = array(
    'en',
    'fr',
);

if(in_array($language, $allowable_languages)) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = $language;
} else {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr';
}
?>
```

*Updated:* In answer to your comment:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $language = $_GET['lang'];

    $allowable_languages = array(
        'en',
        'fr',
    );

    if(in_array($language, $allowable_languages)) {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $language;
    }
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])) {
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'fr';
}
?>
```

Comment: well i only "need" $_GET to register when the language is changed, and i do that by passing a different $lang throught the url.

Comment: If u got a better solution than using $_GET i would love to hear it? Don't really like using it.

Comment: Not really sure about why you would have a problem passing the language in via `GET` parameters. Anyway I have updated my answer with code the to only update the session when the `$_GET['lang']` is provided. If you don't want to update the language then don't send the `lang` parameter in your GET request.

Answer (score 15):

```
$_SESSION['lang'] == "fr";
```

two equal signs mean comparision operator.
assignment is = (one equal)

Answer (score 9):

One obvious thing is

```
$_get["lang"];
```

Variables are case sensitive in PHP. It must be

```
$_GET["lang"];
```

if that doesn't solve your problem, you need to describe in detail what exactly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

U just made a single mistake i.e, u are using wrong syntax it should be $_GET['lang'];

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work because session_start() can't be used directly after session_destroy(). Btw, you don't need to destroy session. Just redefine your variable:

```
$lang = 'fr';
if(isset($_GET['lang']) && in_array($_GET['lang'], array('fr', 'en'))) $lang = $_GET['lang'];
$_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
```

For those who thinks the problem is lower case variable - PHP variables are case insensitive.

Comment: You're wrong, functions' names are case insensitive, but variables aren't.

Comment: $test = 1; $TEST = 2; echo $test; // 1, case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

You are both right. There was a lot of different error. Both the "=" and "==" problem plus the $_GET case sensitive problem.
Here the code i god to work both the $_GET plus the session.
Thanks a lot. I've spend all night trying to find those error plus think i got errorblind.

```
<?php
$lang = $_GET["lang"];
if (($lang == "fr"))
{
session_destroy();
     session_start(); 
$_SESSION['lang'] = "fr";


}
if (($lang == "en"))
{
session_destroy();
     session_start(); 
$_SESSION['lang'] = "en";


}
 if (isset($_SESSION['lang']))
 {


$lang = $_SESSION['lang'];



}
 else  {
$lang = "fr";            
}

?>
```

Comment: The style of that code is just horrible. See the re-factoring I have done in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068145/get-and-session-cant-get-it-to-work/4068193#4068193 as a means to create readable and less repetitive code.